# Qt on Mac: where to find "configure"

Tags: macos, qt

I am very new to Mac.
I downloaded QT SDK Mac Open source (http://get.qt.nokia.com/qtsdk/qt-sdk-mac-opensource-2010.02.dmg) and installed the Package. 
I can run qmake, build samples and run demos, 
but I cannot run **configure** (in order to build the Qt libraries statically).
It says: *-bash: No such file or directory*.
Documentation says I should run this in the "Qt root folder", but what is this folder in Mac?
I looked for it in /usr/bin, /usr/local/Qt4.6, /Developer/Tools/Qt.
Anyway, what is "configure" on Mac. is it an executable or a script?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SDK download is a pre-built binary library. You need to download the [source code](http://get.qt.nokia.com/qt/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2.tar.gz) version of Qt to be able to configure it to build as static libraries.

The configure script only comes with the source code download version.

Answer (score 2):

I think the SDK only provides the headers and libraries hence the reason you can build applications using Qt. To build Qt itself you will need the source package which is a different download.